# Location of os.environ in linux

Tags: python, ubuntu

Am tying to set permanently values for os.environ dictionnary
using shell command.

I put here:

> ./bashrc

```
export myvar="yes"
```

> /etc/profile

```
export myvar="yes"
```

but, os.environ cannot see them after reboot.
So, Question is where os.environ takes variables from in Linux/ubuntu ?

Thanks

Comment: btw you can apply changes to your bash shell immediately by running `source ~/.bashrc` no need to reboot every time ;)

Comment: but, where os.environ takes the values ?

Comment: It doesn't matter where is it taken from. Your problem is that calling [export myvar="yes"] gives a result until next bash logout. Add the line to ~/.bashrc and I'm pretty sure you will see that after reboots.

Comment: @Mikaelblomkvistsson He apparently did that

Comment: @Tensor it should take them from the environment, try running `echo $myvar` and check the output